# Magento2 use Plugins (di.xml)

Tags: magento2, di.xml, plugin

I have created a Plugin. Registered it in `di.xml` All public methods execute.

Can I inject/rewrite/replace (don't know the proper title) protected methods? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cant, and you should not normally.
But you can extend the Class and use the di.xml to get your class injected instead of the original one.